# Obtener primer día y ultimo día de cada mes, iniciando de una fecha

Tags: c#, bucles, while

Espero estén muy bien, soy nuevo en C# espero me puedan ayudar!
Deseo que a partir de una fecha inicial, obtener el primer día de cada mes y el ultimo día de cada mes.
La fecha inicial que se establece es: 01.01.2018 a la fecha (Teniendo en cuenta que si hoy es 16.02.2023, obtener del mes de febrero, hasta el día de hoy)
Espero haberme hecho dar a entenderos bien.

por el momento, solo he podido imprimir del 01.01.2018 al 31.01.2018 ...no he podido del 01.02.2018 al 28.02.2018 y 01.03.2018 al 31.03.2018  y así.. hasta la fecha actual
así va mi código:

```
string fechaIni = "01/01/2018";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(fechaIni);
Console.WriteLine("Inicial: " + fecha.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));

var fechafin = DateTime.Now.Date;
//Console.WriteLine("Final: " + dateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));

if (fecha.Month + 1 < 13)
{
    fechafin = new DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1);
    Console.WriteLine("Fecha Final: " + fechafin.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));                
}
```

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres obtener el primer y último día de cada mes, teniendo en cuenta que en un rango de fechas existen varios meses, ¿De qué forma deseas obtenerlos? ¿Como un arreglo? ¿Deseas solo el primer día del mes de la fecha de inicio y el ultimo día de la fecha de finalización?

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido, necesitas que se impriman el primer y el último día de cada mes, desde fecha de inicio hasta hoy, estoy en lo cierto?. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Pero.. tu codigo hace lo que queres.. solo tenes que hacer que se repita... hasta que llegues a la fecha de fin ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un `for` se usa comumente para iterar en enteros, pero sirve para cualquier cosa, incluido los `DateTime`, ejemplo:

```
string fechaIni = "01/01/2018";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(fechaIni);
Console.WriteLine("Inicial: " + fecha.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));

var fechafin = DateTime.Now.Date;

for (var f = fecha; f < fechafin; f = f.AddMonths(1))
{
     DateTime diaFinal = f.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
     Console.WriteLine(f.ToString() + " " + diaFinal.ToString());
}
```

Comment: mmmm no.. no pidio esto.. ni cerca de lo que pidio.. una lista del primer y ultimo dia del mes....

Comment: @gbianchi detalles

Answer (score 3):

te adjunto una función que trabaje en cierto punto de mi experiencia laboral espero que te sirva obtiene una lista de tuplas que contienen la fecha del primer día y la fecha del último día de cada mes, a partir de una fecha inicial:

```
public static List<(DateTime, DateTime)> GetFirstAndLastDayOfMonth(DateTime startDate, int numberOfMonths) {
List<(DateTime, DateTime)> monthStartEndDates = new List<(DateTime, DateTime)>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonths; i++)
{
    DateTime monthStartDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1);
    DateTime monthEndDate = monthStartDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    monthStartEndDates.Add((monthStartDate, monthEndDate));
    startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
}    
return monthStartEndDates; }
```

llamadola de la siguiente forma:

```
List<(DateTime, DateTime)> monthStartEndDates = GetFirstAndLastDayOfMonth(new DateTime(2023, 2, 1), 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string fecha = "01/01/2018";
DateTime fechaIni = DateTime.Parse( fechaIni );    
DateTime fechaFin = DateTime.Now.Date;

Console.WriteLine( "Fecha inicio: " + fechaFin.ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy" ));

while( true ) {
    fechaIni.AddDays( 1 ); 
    if ( fechaFin != fechaIni ) {
        if( fechaIni.Day == 1 ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Fecha Final: " + fechaIni.AddDay( - 1 ).ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy" )); 
            Console.WriteLine( "Fecha inicio: " + fechaIni.ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy" ));  
        }     
    }
    else {
        if( fechaIni.AddDay( 1 ).Day == 1 ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Fecha Final: " + fechaFin ).ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy" ));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, imprime la primer salida antes del while, ya que de hacerlo dentro, también imprimiría el día anterior, y no es lo que se quiere.
Dentro del while primero incrementa un día (para no repetir), luego en el primer if verifica que no se haya alcanzado la fecha tope, y en el interno, si el día es 1, imprime su valor y el del día anterior.
Por último, dentro del else, tenemos otro if, que detecta si el día siguiente de la fecha tope es 1, en cuyo caso imprime fechaFin.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime fechaInicial = new DateTime (2018, 1, 1);
DateTime fechaFinal = DateTime.Now;
DateTime inicioMes;
DateTime finMes;

for(var fecha = fechaInicial; fecha <= fechaFinal; fecha.AddMonths(1))
{
    inicioMes = new DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Months, 1);
    finMes = new DateTime (fecha.Year, fecha.Months, fecha.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

    Console.WriteLine("Inicio mes: {0}; Fin mes: {1}", inicioMes, finMes);
}
```

Se crea un **ciclo for** que va a recorrer cada mes a partir de la fecha inicial hasta la fecha actual, y por cada mes se obtiene entonces el primer día y último día, finalmente se imprimen los resultados en pantalla.